# Why am I seeing an extra space after the bullet in UL in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Running Windows 7, Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m

It appears that a huge gap has been added to ul lists between the bullet and the first character of the li item. I am using list-style-position: inside; and that is what appears to be adding the space (and I'm not referring to the positioning of the entire line further over - just the space between the bullet and the first character.)

A bare bones HTML5, no other CSS example will show this:

```html
<ul>
 <li style="list-style-position: inside;">One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Compare the space in the first line to the other two lines.

WHY?! This was a BAD design "feature" of Microsoft Internet Explorer, and I sure hope that Google isn't imitating it. The gap appears to be even wider than IE's. So now I am getting additional (and unnecessary) line wraps when viewing a page in Chrome. This means less content can be put into a fixed width/height design. Or smaller fonts to compensate, etc.

A bullet needs only one space between it and the content; to act as a space between the text leading up to the list and each item within the list.

Anyone else seeing this? (This has to be quite recent, as it wasn't a problem just last week when I updated the page)

Comment: Report it as a bug to the chromium team and see what they say. I'm not sure if there's a question here though other than is anyone else seeing this and to that I can say yes.

Comment: Just wanted to add to this that the change happened between versions 52 and 53 in Chrome. I was running 52 and didn't see the space, then upgraded and saw the space.

Comment: Yes, sent similar question to Chrome through their "Report an issue..." link in the drop-down menu - will report back any reply.
But also, needed to know if it was something unique to me and my code, or universal, as well as if the extra space is something people expect to happen and if Chrome has now "fixed" an old bug, or introduced a new one.

Comment: Ha. I *knew* something looked different/wrong with my lists. I can confirm this behavior in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m.

Comment: https://crrev.com/2023433002 might be where the change in Chrome's behavior was introduced.  If so, the change was intentional, and thus not likely to change back in a future version.  :(

Comment: Is there any way to override

`li:dir(rtl)::marker {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I might suggest the following workaround:

```
li:before {
    content: "\a0";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    margin-left: -.5em;
    margin-right: -.5em;
}
```

For example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/AseNe

Hopefully, you will be able to come up with an appropriate selector(s) that will target all relevant `<ul>`s and not require changes in the HTML markup.